# I need a working link to download lwuit bundle version 1.5

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I need a working link to download lwuit bundle version 1.5

**Some Results of my fruitless search**:

> The link to download the LWUIT bundle is broken.
>   https://lwuit.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList , but this
>   seems to be broken. 
>   The LWUIT 1.4 bundle can be downloaded from:
>
> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#lwuit-1.4-oth-JPR

I've searched but i have only been able to get the .jar file for lwuit 1.5 and a link to lwuit 1.4. 
I believe I need the lwuit 1.5 bundle to access the Javadoc, Resource Editor and Examples for lwuit 1.5.

A dropbox link to the bundle might help. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download LWUIT 1.5 from [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/java-mobile/downloads/javaformobiledevicesdownloads-2194042.html) itself.